# Py3k and IPython

Tags: python-3.x, ipython

I'm moving on up to Python 3, but can't seem to find an IPython release for it. The main IPython [release page](http://ipython.scipy.org/moin/Download) doesn't list anything appropriate. Any help in getting IPython working for Py3k would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See the [ipython dev mailing list](http://mail.scipy.org/mailman/listinfo/ipython-dev)

EDIT : see the [Ipython 3 page](http://ipython.scipy.org/moin/Python3) - where now (Jan 2011) it says there is a version for python 3 in source code version only

EDIT: and now [iPython](http://ipython.org/) supports python 3 directly.

Comment: Thanks. For those who don't want to search the listsrv archives, the answer is, "Unsupported now, maybe later."

Comment: IPython has full support for Python3 now, thanks largely to Thomas K.

Comment: if ipython directly supports python3, how can i call them. I have 2.7(default) and 3. I created a virtualenv with python3 as default inside the virtualenv. Now inside the vrtualenv i want ipython to make use of python3 and not python2. how do i invoke ?. The page says just it supports 2.X and 3.X now, no other details apart form that on how to invoke python3 inside ipython ?

Answer (score 9):

Python 3 support has been around for a fairly long time now. You don't need a different version. IPython supports modern versions of Python 2 and 3. You just run IPython with the appropriate interpreter, `python3 ipython.py`. You can install IPython on Python3 by running setup.py with your Python3 interpreter.

Comment: On my system you can also type `ipython3`

Comment: You can do that once IPython's installed, but you need to install it first. This answer's quite old now too; most users will want the IPython Notebook, which has more deps than this answer will resolve. The official story these days is to use a Python distro like Anaconda, but I think they're looking to improve on having only that option for new users. Packaging is better now days, but a lot of people want the latest version.