# Python3k replacement for IPython?

Tags: ipython, python-3.x

So, I'm a huge IPython fan, though I'm sure I don't use nearly all the power it has (mainly tab completion and `?` for introspection, though I also use `%ed` a fair amount).

However, I want to really start working with Python3k, and as [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329218/py3k-and-ipython) states, I'll [need a Snickers](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=video&cd=2&ved=0CDgQtwIwAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DGPRscxQZs8E&ei=M3dRTPjpJcOB8gbk-LyiBA&usg=AFQjCNHKO1filvZtZaJ74vo0E5gI0sejtA&sig2=zMPHsGDFS7rh8JPPJpw3Dg) to tide me over til IPython is ported.

So what are my options for Python3k (preferably that best match IPython features)?

Comment: To update this old question: the latest version of IPython (0.11) has Python 3 support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your platform needs, you may want to take a look at bpython (http://bpython-interpreter.org/).

I don't think it has the `?` introspection shortcut, though.